# How can I add a custom quantity value to a button in Floreant POS?

Tags: java, jbutton, dao

Floreant POS uses a custom UI style

```
public class POSButtonUI extends PlasticButtonUI {
private static final POSButtonUI INSTANCE = new POSButtonUI();

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent b) {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        if (c.isOpaque()) {
            AbstractButton b = (AbstractButton) c;
            if (isToolBarButton(b)) {
                c.setOpaque(false);
            } else if (b.isContentAreaFilled()) {
                g.setColor(c.getBackground());
                g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());

                if (is3D(b)) {
                    Color color1 = c.getBackground();// UIManager.getColor("control");
                    Color color2 = color1.brighter();

                    int x = 0;
                    int y = 0;
                    int width = c.getWidth();
                    int height = c.getHeight();

                    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(x, y, color2, width - 2, height - 2 , color1, true);
                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2.setPaint(gp);
                    g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
                }
            }
        }
        paint(g, c);
    }

}
```

and the PosButton Class extends JButton:

```
public class PosButton extends JButton {
    public static Border border = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
    static Insets margin = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);

    static POSButtonUI ui = new POSButtonUI();

    static {
        UIManager.put("PosButtonUI", "com.floreantpos.swing.POSButtonUI");
    }

    public PosButton() {
        this(null);
    }

    public PosButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        setFont(UIConfig.getButtonFont());

        setFocusPainted(false);
        setMargin(margin);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUIClassID() {
        return "PosButtonUI";
    }

}
```

I'm not sure which class I should try to add a paintComponent method to in order to add a quantity notification in the top right corner of a button for adding modifiers, and I'm not quite sure where to go at this point. There is also a private class "ModifierButton" inside the modifier panel

```
 private class ModifierButton extends PosButton implements ActionListener {

        private MenuModifier menuModifier;

        public ModifierButton(MenuModifier modifier) {
            this.menuModifier = modifier;

            setText(modifier.getName());
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        void updateView(TicketItemModifier ticketItemModifier) {
            if (ticketItemModifier == null || ticketItemModifier.getModifierType() == TicketItemModifier.MODIFIER_NOT_INITIALIZED) {
                setBackground(null);
                //setIcon(null);
                return;
            }

            if (ticketItemModifier.getModifierType() == TicketItemModifier.NORMAL_MODIFIER) {
                //setIcon(normalIcon);
                setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());
            } else if (ticketItemModifier.getModifierType() == TicketItemModifier.NO_MODIFIER) {
                //setIcon(noIcon);
                setBackground(Color.RED.darker());
            } else if (ticketItemModifier.getModifierType() == TicketItemModifier.EXTRA_MODIFIER) {
                //setIcon(extraIcon);
                setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            TicketItemModifierGroup ticketItemModifierGroup = parentTicketItem.findTicketItemModifierGroup(menuModifier, true);
            int modifierCount = ticketItemModifierGroup.countItems(true);
            int maxModifier = ticketItemModifierGroup.getMaxQuantity();


            TicketItemModifier ticketItemModifier = ticketItemModifierGroup.findTicketItemModifier(menuModifier);
            TicketView ticketView = OrderView.getInstance().getTicketView();


            if (ticketItemModifier == null) {
                TicketItemModifier m = ticketItemModifierGroup.addTicketItemModifier(menuModifier, modifierCount >= maxModifier ? TicketItemModifier.EXTRA_MODIFIER : TicketItemModifier.NORMAL_MODIFIER);
                updateView(m);
                ticketView.updateAllView();

                ticketView.selectRow(m.getTableRowNum());
                return;
            }

            int modifierType = TicketItemModifier.MODIFIER_NOT_INITIALIZED;
            if (ticketItemModifier.getModifierType() != null) {
                modifierType = ticketItemModifier.getModifierType().intValue();
            }

            switch (modifierType) {
                case TicketItemModifier.MODIFIER_NOT_INITIALIZED:
                    ticketItemModifier.setModifierType(TicketItemModifier.NORMAL_MODIFIER);
                    updateVisualRepresentation();
                    ticketView.updateAllView();
                    ticketView.selectRow(ticketItemModifier.getTableRowNum());
                    break;

                case TicketItemModifier.NORMAL_MODIFIER:
                case TicketItemModifier.EXTRA_MODIFIER:
                    ticketItemModifier.setModifierType(TicketItemModifier.NO_MODIFIER);
                    updateVisualRepresentation();
                    ticketView.updateAllView();
                    ticketView.selectRow(ticketItemModifier.getTableRowNum());
                    break;

                case TicketItemModifier.NO_MODIFIER:
                    ticketItemModifier.setModifierType(TicketItemModifier.MODIFIER_NOT_INITIALIZED);
                    ticketItemModifierGroup.removeTicketItemModifier(ticketItemModifier);
                    updateView(ticketItemModifier);
                    updateVisualRepresentation();
                    ticketView.updateAllView();
                    ticketView.selectRow(ticketItemModifier.getTableRowNum() - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I guess my question is which of the button classes should i put my paint component method to update the quantity of items in the modifier.